# Prove that $A^*A + I$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix. Prove that $A^*A + I$ is invertible.

I'm not sure what to do because everything I try ends up at $A^*A$ again and not $AA^*$.

Comment: Hint: What would $A^{\ast} A + I$ being *not* invertible imply about the eigenvalues of $A^{\ast}A$?

Answer (score 8):

Suppose $I+A^*A$ is not invertible, then there is some nonzero vector $x$ such that $$0=(I+A^*A)x = x+A^*Ax.$$ This implies $$0=x^*0 = x^*x+x^*A^*Ax = \|x\|^2+\|Ax\|^2\geq\|x\|^2,$$ which contradicts our assumption that $x\neq 0$. Thus $I+A^*A$ is invertible.

Comment: Sorry, I was typing when you posted the same argument, +1.

Comment: That's quite all right. Happens to me all the time :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $B:=A^*A+I$. Using the Euclidean inner product 
$$
(x,y)=x^*y=\sum_{j=1}^n\overline{x_j}y_j
$$
of $\mathbb{C}^n$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$, depending on your assumptions, we get
$$
(x,Bx)=(x,x)+(x,A^*Ax)=(x,x)+(Ax,Ax)=\|x\|^2+\|Ax\|^2\geq \|x\|^2.
$$
Therefore, if $Bx=0$, it follows that $\|x\|=0$, i.e. $x=0$.

So $B$ is a square matrix and $\mbox{Ker} B=\{0\}$, i.e. it is injective.

By the [rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), it follows that $B$ is invertible.